# redux-form Field and Checkbox react-toolbox value checked from object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form

I have this data:

```
...
initialValues: {
  alarm: 'normal',
  days: { mon: true, tue: true, wed: true, thu: false, friday: true }
}
...
```

to render, I do the following.

```
<Field name="days" component={({ input }) => {
  return (
    <div className='days-container'>
      <Checkbox label='Monday' checked={input.value.mon} onChange={input.onChange} />
      <Checkbox label='Tuesday' checked={input.value.tue} onChange={input.onChange} />
      ...
    </div>
  )
}}/>
```

but days value becomes Boolean:

```
days: true
```

as you would to maintain the initial structure?

Comment: you can edit the post you know?

Comment: Modified,  I did not see the option to edit

Answer (score 1):

I did it this way

```
<Field name="days" label='Days' component={({ input, label }) => {
  return (
    <div className='days-container'>
      <span className='label'>{label}</span>
      {[ 'mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'friday'].map((name, index) =>
          <Checkbox label={name} checked={input.value[name]} key={index} onChange={checked => {
            const setter = {};
            setter[name]=checked;
            input.onChange({...input.value, ...setter})}} />
      )}
    </div>
  )
}}/>
```

there a better way?

Comment: This is really good. In my case I ended up creating a custom reducer plugin for redux form and handling each tickbox separately by listening on it's onclick event... This is much easier.